# English expression for facial hair (beard) of a woman

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific term for facial hair around the mouth (or a beard) if the person in question is female? I'm looking for a translation of the German "Damenbart". Some [dictionaries](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Damenbart.html) provide

> facial hair

as a translation, but that is not quite specific enough compared to the German term. Ideally, I'm looking for a phrase to insert into a statement of the form

> She has a ...

Comment: Female facial hair!http://m.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Female-Facial-Hair

Comment: She has excessive facial hair.

Comment: The ladies to describe it as a beard. Hence "Bearded Ladies"

Comment: This is what I'd call a  [bearded woman](http://static3.nachrichten.at/storage/scl/import/alfa/kultur/1057252_m3w561h315q80s1v50956_xio-fcmsimage-20140512200425-006007-53710d29b8b25-.57f18349-88f7-4116-a4d8-fefc87f45e46.jpg?version=1402367672) She is of course Conchita Wurst the winner of the Eurovision song contest, from Austria.

Comment: This is what [down](http://cdn.jolie.de/bilder/ups-da-hat-madonna-alias-iron-man-in-spe-wohl-vergessen-400x550-248696.jpg) looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the facial hair is very soft and has a slightly matted appearance it is sometimes referred to as ***down***. Some compare it to the skin that covers a peach.  It is also used for very young children, especially newborns.

> **down** *noun*
>   2.1. Fine, soft hair on the face or body of a person:
>   *the little girl had a covering of golden down on her head*
>
> <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/down#down-2)</sup>

For facial hair that is visible above the lips, there are two ways of calling it; (fine) ***upper-lip hair***, which many would posit is an euphemism for the more masculine term, ***moustache***. Female moustaches aren't the same as men's. Firstly they don't normally grow beyond a certain length, and secondly they're usually much softer and more delicate in appearance. [image] If you type *[upper-lip hair](https://www.google.com/search?q=upper-lip%20hair&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=upper-lip%20hair&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.18664j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22upper-lip%20hair%22)* on Google  you'll find many instances and images

> **moustache** *noun*
>   1. A strip of hair left to grow above the upper lip.
>   *She has a pencil-thin moustache on her upper lip*
>
> <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moustache)</sup>

A more precise medical term for facial and body hair is

> ***Vellus hair***
>   Vellus hair is short, fine, light-colored, and barely noticeable hair
>   that develops on most of a person's body during childhood. Exceptions
>   include the lips, the back of the ear, the palm of the hand, the sole
>   of the foot, some external genital areas, the navel and scar tissue. [...]Vellus hair is most easily observed on children and adult women, as they generally have less terminal hair to obscure it.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellus_hair)</sup>

For hair that is visible around the chin area, you could  call it *chin hair*, but I barely read this term in depilatory products. Generally the most common and most understood term is the one discovered by the OP himself, *facial hair*.

Comment: Great answer. (BTW, I just heard "moustache" being used on the Big Bang Theory.)

Answer (score 3):

> **Hirsutism**: abnormal growth of hair on a person's face and body, especially on a woman.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, it's called [peach fuzz](https://www.google.com/search?q=peach+fuzz&tbm=isch), and it can apply to teens as well as women.